# concatenate boost::mpl::string

Tags: c++, string, boost, boost-mpl

How I can concatenate boost::mpl::string?
The following code produce errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<
   boost::mpl::string<'ab'>,
   boost::mpl::string<'cd'>,
   boost::mpl::string<'ef'>
> slist;

typedef boost::mpl::fold<
   slist,
   boost::mpl::string<>,
   boost::mpl::push_back<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2>
>::type string;

int main() {
   std::cout << boost::mpl::c_str<string>::value << std::endl;
}
```

errors:

> In file included from source.cpp:3:0:
> string.hpp: In instantiation of
> 'boost::mpl::push_back_impl<
> boost::mpl::string_tag
> >::applyboost::mpl::string<, boost::mpl::string<24930> >':
> boost/mpl/push_back.hpp:32:1:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::push_back<
> boost::mpl::string<>, boost::mpl::string<24930>
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/has_type.hpp:20:1:
> instantiated from 'const bool
> boost::mpl::aux::has_type<
> boost::mpl::push_backboost::mpl::string<,
> boost::mpl::string<24930> >,
> mpl_::bool_
> >::value' boost/mpl/aux_/has_type.hpp:20:1:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::aux::has_type<
> boost::mpl::push_backboost::mpl::string<,
> boost::mpl::string<24930> >,
> mpl_::bool_
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/quote.hpp:56:5:
> instantiated from 'boost::mpl::quote2<
> boost::mpl::push_back
> >::applyboost::mpl::string<, boost::mpl::string<24930> >'
> boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply_wrap.hpp:49:1:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<
> boost::mpl::quote2boost::mpl::push_back,
> boost::mpl::string<>,
> boost::mpl::string<24930>
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/bind.hpp:207:21:
> instantiated from 'boost::mpl::bind2<
> boost::mpl::quote2boost::mpl::push_back,
> mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2>
> >::applyboost::mpl::string<, boost::mpl::string<24930> >'
> boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply_wrap.hpp:49:1:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<
> boost::mpl::protect<
> boost::mpl::bind2boost::mpl::quote2<boost::mpl::push_back,
> mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> >, 0
> >, boost::mpl::string<>, boost::mpl::string<24930>
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply.hpp:73:1:
> instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<
> boost::mpl::push_back<mpl_::arg<1>,
> mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::mpl::string<>,
> boost::mpl::string<24930>
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/fold_impl.hpp:87:85:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::aux::fold_impl<
> 3, boost::mpl::v_iter<
> boost::mpl::vectorboost::mpl::string<24930,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>,
> boost::mpl::string<25958> >, 0l
> >, boost::mpl::v_iter<
> boost::mpl::vectorboost::mpl::string<24930,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>,
> boost::mpl::string<25958> >, 3l
> >, boost::mpl::string<>, boost::mpl::push_back<mpl_::arg<1>,
> mpl_::arg<2> >
> >' boost/mpl/fold.hpp:39:18:   instantiated from 'boost::mpl::fold<
> boost::mpl::vectorboost::mpl::string<24930,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>,
> boost::mpl::string<25958> >
> , boost::mpl::string<>, boost::mpl::push_back<mpl_::arg<1>,
> mpl_::arg<2> >
> >' source.cpp:18:2:   instantiated from here string.hpp:207:53: error:
> 'value' is not a member of
> 'boost::mpl::string<24930>' In file
> included from
> boost/mpl/back_inserter.hpp:18:0, from
> boost/mpl/aux_/inserter_algorithm.hpp:18,
> from boost/mpl/copy.hpp:20, from
> string.hpp:26, from source.cpp:3:
> boost/mpl/push_back.hpp: In
> instantiation of
> 'boost::mpl::push_back<
> boost::mpl::push_backboost::mpl::string<,
> boost::mpl::string<24930> >,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>
> >': boost/mpl/aux_/has_type.hpp:20:1:
> instantiated from 'const bool
> boost::mpl::aux::has_type<
> boost::mpl::push_back<
> boost::mpl::push_backboost::mpl::string<,
> boost::mpl::string<24930> >,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>
> >, mpl_::bool_
> >::value' boost/mpl/aux_/has_type.hpp:20:1:
> instantiated from
> 'boost::mpl::aux::has_type<
> boost::mpl::push_back<
> boost::mpl::push_backboost::mpl::string<,
> boost::mpl::string<24930> >,
> boost::mpl::string<25444>
> >, mpl_::bool_
> >' boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/quote.hpp:56:5:
> instantiated from 'boost::mpl::quote2<
> boost::mpl::push_back

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef boost::mpl::vector<
   boost::mpl::string<'a','b'>,
   boost::mpl::string<'c','d'>,
   boost::mpl::string<'e','f'>
> slist;


typedef boost::mpl::reverse_fold<
   slist,
   mpl::string<>,
   boost::mpl::copy<mpl::_1, mpl::back_inserter<mpl::_2> >
>::type string;

int main() {
   std::cout << boost::mpl::c_str<string>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//it's very easy to do this to have the same out put: abcdef

#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef mpl::string<'ab','cd','ef'> string;

int main() {
   std::cout << mpl::c_str<string>::value << std::endl;
}
```