# Initializing a static char based on template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to do something like this :

```
template<typename T>
const char * toStr(T num)
{
    thread_local static char rc[someval*sizeof(T)] str = "0x000...\0"; // num of zeros depends on size of T
    // do something with str
    return str;
}
```

I'm guessing there's some template metaprogramming I'd have to do but I'm not sure where to start.

Edit:

I found a related question here: [How to concatenate a const char* in compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965003/how-to-concatenate-a-const-char-in-compile-time)

But I don't want the dependency on boost.

Comment: 1. The size should (probably) be `3+2*sizeof(T)`. 2. `\0` in this case adds a second useless null terminator. I don't think you want to have it. 3. I'd say you don't need to initialize the array at all. Just `sprintf` your number into it at each call. 4. Why not use `std::string`s instead of `char` arrays if you're using C++?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this was just a demonstrative example. 3+2*sizeof(T) is indeed what the current implantation uses for the size. I forgot about the implicit string literal. Thanks for the reminder. I'm using an implementation inspired by this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33447587 because this is a performance sensitive application. The result is copied anyway by the calling function so I dont want the extra string allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you want but... if you want that the `str` initial value is created compile time and if you accept that `toStr()` call and helper function (`toStrH()` in the following example) a C++14 example follows

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... I>
const char * toStrH (T const & num, std::index_sequence<I...> const &)
 {
   static char str[3U+sizeof...(I)] { '0', 'x', ((void)I, '0')..., '\0' };

   // do someting with num

   return str;
 }

template <typename T>
const char * toStr (T const & num)
 { return toStrH(num, std::make_index_sequence<(sizeof(T)<<1U)>{}); }

int main()
 {
   toStr(123);
 }
```

If you need a C++11 solution, substitute `std::make_index_sequence()` and `std::index_sequence` isn't difficult.

Comment: Aha! That's quite a clever use of the comma operator.